# not receiving all data from database, yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Controller action to render index page

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $posts = Posts::find()->all();
        $user = User::find()->all;
        return $this->render('index', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }
```

View:

```
<? foreach ($posts as $post){?>
    <div class="well">
        <h5><?=$user[$post->user_id-1]->login ?></h5>
        <?=$post->text ?>
    </div>
    <?} ?>
```

Posts texts are displayed but users logins not. Why? 
var_dump($users) shows nothing. I checked this table. There are some records in users table.

Comment: short open tags, are they enabled? are you checking for errors?

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($post, $user);` ? The expression `$post->user_id-1` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $posts = Posts::find()->all();
    $user = User::find()->all();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'posts' => $posts,
        'user' => $user
    ]);
}
```

use `User::find()->all();` **not** `User::find()->all;`

Comment: okay one more thing you can try as the naming conventions suggests you are using Posts (plural), however User is singular. Try Users to see if it works.